# How to implement carousel (card slider) with Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, carousel, android-jetpack-compose

I had been using  [this library](https://github.com/IslamKhSh/CardSlider/blob/master/README.md) to implement carousel in the View system.
How do I implement carousel in Jetpack Compose?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well... It depends of the which feature you need from this library, but for "simple" pager you can use Pager Accompanist library.

https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/pager

And you can check the docs here:

https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/

Comment: Note that https://github.com/google/accompanist now lists Pager as "Soon to be deprecated - Upstreamed in Compose 1.4".

Comment: This is probably because it will be included in the compose UI toolkit library.

Answer (score 3):

Try this way Using `HorizontalPager`

```
@Composable
fun BuildLoginSlider() {
  val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 1)
  val sliderList = listOf()

  HorizontalPager(
    count = sliderList.size, state = pagerState,
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 150.dp),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
  ) { page ->
    Card(
      colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(Color.Transparent),
      shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
      elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(0.dp),
      modifier = Modifier
        .graphicsLayer {

          val pageOffset = calculateCurrentOffsetForPage(page).absoluteValue

          lerp(
            start = 0.85f,
            stop = 1f,
            fraction = 1f - pageOffset.coerceIn(0f, 1f)
          ).also { scale ->
            scaleX = scale
            scaleY = scale
          }
          alpha = lerp(
            start = 0.5f,
            stop = 1f,
            fraction = 1f - pageOffset.coerceIn(0f, 1f)
          )
        }
      // .aspectRatio(0.5f)
    ) {
      AsyncImage(
        model = Builder(LocalContext.current)
          .data(sliderList[page])
          .crossfade(true)
          .scale(FILL)
          .build(),
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier
          .offset {
            // Calculate the offset for the current page from the
            // scroll position
            val pageOffset =
              this@HorizontalPager.calculateCurrentOffsetForPage(page)
            // Then use it as a multiplier to apply an offset
            IntOffset(
              x = (70.dp * pageOffset).roundToPx(),
              y = 0,
            )
          }
      )
    }

  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: I tried using this with material3. After a long struggle, I managed to reach an error-free code. But I couldn't figure out how to add the pictures in the `listOf` section. How can I do it?

Comment: @MehmetCanErtan you need to pass a list of urls  in `sliderList`